# Div child not setting height to 100% on chrome or ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have this container div which has 2 more child div, i want the div with the class "movablebartoggleswitch" have a height of 100% of its container div, this must work in IE8 and in chrome, but it works either in one or another but not in both, could you tell me what's wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="configdiv" class="maindiv">
<div class="simpletext">    
</div>
<br/>
<div name="containertoggleswitch" class="containertoggleswitch">
<div class="movablebartoggleswitch">        
</div>
    <div class="bartoggleswitch">       
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>

.maindiv
{
background-color:#00ABA9;
color:#FFF;
position:absolute;
width:250px;
height:500px;
font-family: 'Segoe UI';
font-weight: lighter;
font-size:20;
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
/*Works for all browsers except IE*/
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
}
.simpletext
{
width:100%;
}

.containertoggleswitch
{
width:100px;
height:30px;
background-color:#FFF;
position:relative;
}

.bartoggleswitch
{
position :relative;
color:#000; 
background-color:inherit;
height:100%;
width:100%;
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
border-color:#FFABAF;
}

.movablebartoggleswitch
{
clear:both;
position:absolute;  
z-index:10; 
width:20%;
height:100%;
background-color:#000;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is is that the `border` styles are causing the the element to expand, making the height change. To fix this, use `box-sizing: border-box` to change the box model to cater for padding to be part of widths

http://jsfiddle.net/XyQB4/

Comment: or shall I say cause the element to expand

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help you or not, but I had a similar height issue with Chrome (worked fine elsewhere).  The way I got it to work was in the HTML code for the DIV id, I put `style="min-height: 660px"` - or whatever height you need it to be.  I didn't have a `min-height` or `height:auto` in my CSS for the DIV id.  I do have... `body, html{height:100%; height:auto;}`